# Apache RewriteMap with URL's that may or may not contain a query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have a `RewriteMap` that contains the following examples:

```
/home /
/index?q=video /videos
/index?q=media /media
/epic.html /epic
```

How can we `RewriteMap` to match urls that may or may not have a QUERYSTRING attached to it?

We are currently using:

```
    RewriteMap mappings txt:/data/redirect_mappings
    RewriteCond ${mappings:$1|Unknown} !Unknown
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${mappings:$1?%{QUERY_STRING}|$1?%{QUERY_STRING}} [L,R=301,QSD]
```

However, it does not seem to be taking any effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
RewriteMap mappings txt:/data/redirect_mappings

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteCond ${mappings:%1|NOTFOUND} !NOTFOUND
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${mappings:%1}? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond ${mappings:$1|NOTFOUND} !NOTFOUND
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${mappings:$1} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unknown is the default value i believe. Your solution will not connect the query string